# How to know if a spinner item has been selected in android?

Tags: android, spinner

How can I know if an item in spinner has been selected in android??

Answer (score 5):

See here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

You have to implement an `OnItemSelectedListener`.

Here the example from the link:

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
        View view, int pos, long id) {
      Toast.makeText(parent.getContext()), "The planet is " +
          parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
      // Do nothing.
    }
}

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
```

You could also use an anonymous inner method if you don't want to explicitly declare a class for your listener.

Comment: I would accept this answer. That is pretty much out of the box. The link is even there.

Answer (score 0):

for the spinner, you need to implement [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html).